# powershell check for existence of multiple inputs

Tags: powershell, input, file-exists

I need to check if files from input exists.

1. I split multiple inputs for example BWMDL.VML BWMDL.STA etc and write out files that are already in folder
2. I check if files from input are present in folder or not.

But I'm getting True, even if the file doesnt exists, also the output from test-path is printed twice, with different result.

```
Set-Variable -Name Files -Value (Read-Host "instert file name") 
Set-Variable -Name FromPath -Value ("C:\Users\Desktop\AP\AP\parser\*.VML" , "C:\Users\Desktop\AP\AP\parser\*.STA")
Set-Variable -Name NameOfFiles (Get-ChildItem -Path $FromPath "-Include *.VML, *.STA" -Name)

Write-Host "FILES IN FOLDER:"
$NameOfFiles

Write-host "---------------------"
Write-host "FILES FROM INPUT: "
Splitted
Write-host "---------------------"

Write-host "FILE EXISTS: "
ForEach ($i in Splitted) {
    FileToCheck
}

function Splitted {
    $Files -Split " "
}

function FileToCheck {
    Test-Path $FromPath -Filter $Files -PathType Leaf
}
```

For example I'm getting like this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjrt8.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are over complicating this.
Once you get the names of all files with extension .VML or .STA in an array, you do not have to use `Test-Path` anymore, since you know the files in array `$NameOfFiles` actually do exist, otherwise `Get-ChildItem` would not have listed them.

This means you can get rid of the helper functions you have defined, which BTW should have been written on top of your code, so **before** calling on them.

Try

```
$Files    = (Read-Host "instert file name(s) separated by space characters" ) -split '\s+'
$FromPath = 'C:\Users\Desktop\AP\AP\parser'

# if you need to recurse through possible subfolders
$NameOfFiles = (Get-ChildItem -Path $FromPath -Include '*.VML', '*.STA' -File -Recurse).Name

# without recursion (so if files are directly in the FromPath):
# $NameOfFiles = (Get-ChildItem -Path $FromPath -File | Where-Object {$_.Extension -match '\.(VML|STA)'}).Name

Write-Host "FILES IN FOLDER:"
$NameOfFiles

Write-host "---------------------"
Write-host "FILES FROM INPUT: "
$Files
Write-host "---------------------"

Write-host "FILE EXISTS: "
foreach ($file in $Files) { ($NameOfFiles -contains $file) }
```

Output should look like

```
instert file name(s) separated by space characters: BWMDL.VML BWMDL.STA
FILES IN FOLDER:
BWMDL.STA
BWMDL.VML
---------------------
FILES FROM INPUT: 
BWMDL.VML
BWMDL.STA
---------------------
FILE EXISTS: 
True
True
```